# Zend Amf for Flash Builder 4

Tags: flash, builder, zend-amf

I have created a flash builder 4 project and using the zend amf as the IDE suggests.
But now its time to test in a online apache enviroment.
It is any security risks?
Can i easily move or hide the zend amf?

thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Zend_Amf with Adobe flash builder 4 and it works without any problems.

The only security risk that AMF provides is actually allowing a user to execute commands through AMF as much as he wants. you can prevent them by logging the requests to the Zend_Amf server file. more security related tasks can be achieved by limited the ip address and the number of requests that be called to that service, this kind of defense can be achieved both by the apache configuration file and by php.